# Personalizando DataGridView

Tags: c#

Como puedo solucionar este problema a la hora de personalizar mi `DataGridView`? Intente modificando estilos por defecto, los estilos de cada `Row`, y `Header`, pero sigue apareciendo igual.

[image: Este es el estilo que he estado creando]
[image: Pero este es el que se muestra cuando se ejecuta el programa]

Se agradece cualquier comentario que pueda ayudar.
Pura Vida desde Costa Rica!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Es difícil que puedas recibir ayuda sin mostrar que has intentado, que es lo que has cambiado.

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda asignar la propiedad `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` para que aplique los estilos

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

entonces cambias el estilo

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle;
style.Font = new Font("Arial", 8.5F, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```